# Android: How to change specific name of the generated apk file in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, apk

By default IDE genarate a apk like `app-debug.apk` or `app-release.apk` file but I need to generate specific name of the **Apk** of the App.

For Example:
My application name is **iPlanter** so i need to generate **`iPlanter-debug.apk`** or **`iPlanter-release.apk`** instead of  `app-debug.apk` or `app-release.apk` respectively.

Thanks,

Comment: Ever since VB3.0 developers have been able to use a GUI to do something simple as this, yet in Android Studio 3.X we have devolved to editing script files.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Step 1:**
Go to **root** of the *main project*, under **app** , right click on **app** and refactor the app into specific name (*example iPlanter*) and press ok

**Step 2:**
Go to Project Setting file which is **`setting.gradle` file**

`setting.gradle` file contains

```
include ':app'
```

Now need to replace app by specific name.

For Example 
app replace by iPlanter in **include ':app'**
it looks like below

```
include ':iPlanter'
```

then Sync project, after that run your application. 
Finally, App generate an apk like **`iPlanter-debug.apk`** or **`iPlanter-release.apk`** file.

Comment: Error:Project 'app' not found in root project 'iPlanter'. I am getting this error @kgsharathkumar

Comment: @pcpriyanka, now check , i added complete steps.. :)

Comment: May I select rename directory or module ?

Comment: thanks :) its working now how to remove debug.apk and release.apk ?

Comment: both will work @pcpriyanka, if u use module no need to go for step2

Comment: @pcpriyanka, "debug" and "release" are required to identified the build type.

Comment: well, I don't know how about you, but usually the top level module is already called similarly to the name I want for the whole application and its executable - and I can't have a module 'myapp' in 'myapp' module. What is your solution for that? (Although I like the approach)

Answer (score 17):

Just add

```
   archivesBaseName = "NAME_YOU_WANT"
```

in the android{} part of your gradle file.

You'll get "NAME_YOU_WANT-release.apk" as name of the generated file.

Comment: how to get rid of the `-release` suffix and make it `NAME_YOU_WANT.apk`?

Answer (score 11):

You just have to add following one line of code in app level gradle.

1. For name only

> archivesBaseName = "NAME_YOU_WANT"

```
 defaultConfig {

       applicationId "com.PACKAGENAME"

       minSdkVersion Integer.parseInt(MIN_SDK_LIBRARY)

       targetSdkVersion Integer.parseInt(TARGET_SDK)

       versionCode 11

       versionName "2.3"

       multiDexEnabled true

       archivesBaseName = "NAME_YOU_WANT"


    }
```

2. Name with version

> archivesBaseName = "NAME_YOU_WANT" + versionName

```
defaultConfig {

   applicationId "com.PACKAGENAME"

   minSdkVersion Integer.parseInt(MIN_SDK_LIBRARY)

   targetSdkVersion Integer.parseInt(TARGET_SDK)

   versionCode 11

   versionName "2.3"

   multiDexEnabled true

   archivesBaseName = "NAME_YOU_WANT" + versionName
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use this for app name with current date and version

```
android {
def version = "2.4";
def milestone = "1";
def build = "0";
def name = getDate()+"APP NAME WHAT YOU WANT"+"v"+version


signingConfigs {
    config {
       ….
   }
}
compileSdkVersion Integer.parseInt(COMPILE_SDK)
buildToolsVersion BUILD_TOOLS_VERSION
defaultConfig {
   applicationId "com.PACKAGENAME"
   minSdkVersion Integer.parseInt(MIN_SDK_LIBRARY)
   targetSdkVersion Integer.parseInt(TARGET_SDK)
   versionCode 11
   versionName "2.3"
   multiDexEnabled true
}
buildTypes {
   debug {
       applicationVariants.all { variant ->
           variant.outputs.each { output ->
               def apk = output.outputFile;
               def newName;
               newName = apk.name.replace("-" + variant.buildType.name, "")
                       .replace(project.name, name);
               newName = newName.replace("-", "-" + version + "-" + milestone +
                       "-" + build + "-");
               output.outputFile = new File(apk.parentFile, newName);
           }
       }
   }
```

Comment: app level build.gradle file, not in project level file

Comment: What about AndroidStudio 3 ?

Answer (score 3):

This will help you. This code will create app name like iPlanter-release.apk or iPlanter-debug.apk

```
buildTypes {
   applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    variant.outputs.each { output ->
        project.ext { appName = 'iPlanter' }
        def newName = output.outputFile.name
        newName = newName.replace("app-", "$project.ext.appName-")
        output.outputFile = new File(output.outputFile.parent, newName)
     }
  }
}
```

**Update:**

```
  applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    variant.outputs.all {
        outputFileName = "iPlanter_${variant.versionName}(${variant.versionCode}).apk"
    }
  }
```

It set name like

> iPlanter_0.0.1(25).apk

Answer (score 3):

For Android Studio 3, this works for me:

```
applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.all { output ->
            outputFileName = new File("AppName-" + variant.versionName + ".apk");
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
defaultConfig{
      applicationVariants.all { variant ->
                changeAPKName(variant, defaultConfig)
            }
}

def changeAPKName(variant, defaultConfig) {
    variant.outputs.each { output ->
        if (output.zipAlign) {
            def file = output.outputFile
            output.packageApplication.outputFile = new File(file.parent, "Your APK NAME")
        }
        def file = output.packageApplication.outputFile
        output.packageApplication.outputFile = new File(file.parent, "Your APK NAME")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For Android Studio 3.1 this works for me:

```
android {
     ...............
     ...............

     applicationVariants.all { variant ->
            changeAPKName(variant, defaultConfig)
        }

  compileOptions {
       sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
       targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
       }

      .................................
      .................................
     }
```

and

```
def changeAPKName(variant, defaultConfig) {
    variant.outputs.all { output ->
        outputFileName = new File("xxxxx" + variant.versionName +".apk")
    }
}
```

Comment: Now that I've done this, studio can't find the path of apk to install! This is because it's expecting another apk name.

Answer (score 0):

On my PC, it suffices to rename (through refactor) **app** to the desired name **yourName**. After that, `include ':app'` in setting.grandle file is changed to `include ':yourName'`. However, in my case I need to close/reopen Android Studio because of sync error. As a result, obtain **apk** something like **yourName-debug.apk** and **yourName-release.apk**.