# Deploying Android app to different app stores with same code but diffent apk package name

Tags: android-studio, deployment, android-gradle-plugin, app-store, package-name

I would like to know if it is possible to modify the AndroidStudio project for my app so that different modules or variants are in it that have the same code base, but different apk package name, one for each app store I want publish the app.

For example:

```
com.myapp.android.google.app

com.myapp.android.amazon.app

com.myapp.android.another.app
```

According to this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39654620/android-how-to-change-specific-name-of-the-generated-apk-file-in-android-studio) it seems that this kind of compilation is possible but it is not specific to my question about deploying to different app stores.